# Flutter TextEditingController retain value without hitting done button

Tags: flutter

Simple Add Place widget

- Title Text Field
- Container - Render image from camera
- Button - Activates camera device

I thought having a controller connected to TextField would automatically save the state of the input value.  However, from my example, if I input the text without click "done" and immediately click on "Take Picture" button.  The TextField input value is cleared after coming back from camera operation.

How to Reproduce Problem:

1. Input text into the field
2. Immediately click on the Camera button without click done / check or hit enter on the keyboard
3. Take a picture confirm.
4. Come back to page the TextField is empty

Example Code:

AddPlacePage StatefulWidget

```
Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                  controller: _titleController,
                ),

                ImageInput(),
              ],
            ),
```

ImageInput  StatefulWidget

```
  class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  File _storedImage;

  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );
    setState(() {
      _storedImage = imageFile;
    });
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          ...
          child: _storedImage != null
              ? Image.file(
                  _storedImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: double.infinity,
                )
              : Text(
                  'No Image Taken',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),

        Expanded(
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
            label: Text('Take Picture'),
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: () => _takePicture(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Question:

How can I modify TextField's controller to retain input value even after exiting the application to access device camera?

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
  controller: _titleController,
),
```

I did try to create a local variable and try to use onChange:

```
   String _inputValue

   build(BuildContext context){

     ...   
     TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
        controller: _titleController,
        onChange: (value) => _inputValue = value;
     ),
```

However the effect is the same once returning from the camera as Flutter re-reders the page, both `_inputValue` and _titleController.text is cleared.

Example code:
https://github.com/erich5168/flutter_camera_example

Comment: declare a static variable in your class, then assign the text field value to it using on text changed method.

Comment: This should not happen, the text should remain on the text field. Your TextField is on a different view than the button that triggers the camera?

Comment: @OMiShah I did... see code below question I used an onChnage... but did not work

Comment: @JoãoSoares Yes you are right... AddPlacePage has a scaffold [ this is where the TextField resides ].  And have extracted the Camera button and the image preview to a separate StatefulWidget.

Comment: @JoãoSoares I have added github repo... hope this makes it easier... thank you

Comment: I'm going to take a look at your code and try to understand what might be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [share preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save the String to device then call it when you back to text field. This is how I implement:

```
class LocalStorage {
  static SharedPreferences instance;

  static Future init() async {
    instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static dynamic getValue(String key, dynamic emptyValue) {
    if (LocalStorage.instance.containsKey(key)) {
      return LocalStorage.instance.get(key);
    }
    return emptyValue;
  }
}
```

set it to text field:

```
TextEditingController _usernameController =
  new TextEditingController(text: LocalStorage.getValue('UserName', ''));
```

Comment: This solution looks like an overkill for something that should just work by default, if the code is properly written.